# Cannot add answer from Project Management SE to Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When selecting Project Management from the drop-down to add an answer to my Careers profile, the processing animation just continues to spin (and I can select other SE sites in the drop-down and the spinner spins only as long as it needs to before a result is given (either no answers or a list of answers).  I tried to see if the infinite spinning is limited to beta sites, but received inconsistent results.

Comment: Reproduced: `/cv/widgets/stackexchangeanswers/getTopAnswers?site=<sitename>` throws a 500 error for all beta sites I tried. Graduate sites work fine. On Chrome 18.0.1025.142 m Win, no scripts / extensions, cleared cache - although for this one it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report jcmeloni.

This is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Jason - the list now shows, but the "add" function doesn't work (click add, it spins -- Chrome and FF, at least) - do you want another   report or does this count?

Comment: @jcmeloni: This counts.

Comment: @jcmeloni: Can you try again?

Comment: @jcmeloni: YAY! I DID SOMETHING GOOT!